# tokenizing string in bash problem

Tags: shell, tokenize

```
    tokens='a,b'
    IFS=',' read -ra a <<<$tokens
    for i in "${a[@]}"; do
       echo "$i |"
    done
```

outputs

```
    a b |
```

but

```
    IFS=',' read -ra a <<<'a,b'
    for i in "${a[@]}"; do
       echo "$i |"
    done
```

outputs correctly

```
a |
b |
```

how do I make the first one work?  I'm confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need double quotes around $token

```
 cat a

 tokens='a,b'
     IFS=',' read -ra a <<< "$tokens"
     for i in "${a[@]}"; do
        echo "$i |"
     done

 ./a
 a |
 b |
```